# how to trigger class and hover effect using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is ti possible to set the below css  using jquery ??

like .addClass() in jquery

```
.macbook:not(:hover) .macbook-lid {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
}
.macbook:not(:hover) .macbook-lid:before {
  width: 94%;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do....do you want to add a hover effect using jQery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**CSS**

```
.macbook:not(:hover) .macbook-lid {  }
.test{
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
  transform: rotate3d(-1, 0, 0, 91deg);
}
.macbook:not(:hover) .macbook-lid:before {
  width: 94%;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.macbook').on('click',function(){
    $('.macbook-lid').toggleClass('test');
});
```

`Tried` to create a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fp9E/)

Answer (score 0):

> Is ti possible to set the below css using jquery ??

Yes.

JS:

```
$('.element').hover(function() {
$(this).addClass('class-below');
}, function {
$(this).removeClass('class-below');
});
```

CSS :

```
.class-below:before { .... }
```

You will use this class to add below logic.